# Visual Basic forms opening in another area

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms

i have some forms which have a set minimum and maximum resolution to 400,400 so it is always a square and cannot be adjusted using the control box

my main issue is that whenever a new form opens or closes, the forms are always opening diagonally down to the right or up to the left and i want to stop this happening as it looks bad if you keep opening and closing the forms (as you can see the previous forms in the background)

You can reproduce this by creating a new visual basic forms project and creating a button which opens another form, you can see that the new form is not directly over the other form.

with thanks,
forp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the forms window properties, there is a property named `StartPosition`. This you have to set it to `Manual`, and that's it.

```
Form1.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the location of the new form, for example to put its top-left in the same place as the current form's location:

```
Private Sub bnShowFormB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnShowFormB.Click
    Dim formB As New Form2() With {.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                                   .Location = Me.Location}
    formB.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: You likely need to set the StartPosition to Manual.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thanks, that makes it tidier.